# ssh on local area network works to server but from remote client doesn't

Tags: router, ssh, dns, port-forwarding

I have a local server that has DYNDNS installed with a domain name 'mydomain.com'.  On my local area network, I can ssh to the local server using it's local IP address successfully.  This tells me that port 22 is working on the local server.  I cannot, however ssh to the mydomain.com!  Yet, nslookup of mydomain.com gives the external IP address of the server, and my router is set to forward port 22 to the local IP address.

Also, from an AWS client, I can ping the mydomain.com, and nslookup mydomain.com, yet again, ssh username@mydomain.com returns Network is unreachable and using the -v option stops when trying the connection to port 22 using the correct external IP address.  I have refreshed the DNS caches, restarted the machines and router, and examined the .ssh/config and the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file for any oddities and see nothing.  The local IP address of the server is set as static and that IP address is used in the router port forwarding.

What else should I check or test to find why I have this behavior?

Comment: Try forwarding a different external port like port 80 to port 22 on your server, then specify that external port when running your SSH client. Some ISPs block port 22 by default because it is one of the most-attacked ports, along with the SMB ports.

Comment: I find that port 80 doesn’t work either. Apparently mydomain.com isn’t actually going to my external ip address and even though I have the port forwarding set to the servers internal ip, it’s not happening. Is this something to do with CNAME records or such?  Http://example.com should work I would think.